# Displaying a final price as currency format and reading from file in java

Tags: java

I'm nearly finished with a program I've been writing for quite some time for a school final assignment.  It's 99% complete, but I'd like to add a couple things to make it as perfect as possible and need help.

I'd like to display the final price of an order in currency format, but have only figured out a way to format as currency if it's in my tostring method.

There's also bonus points to be had with this if I create a method that creates an order from a file. (ex: orders 1 Reece's Pieces, 6 sugar cookies, 1 chocolate chip cookie, and 1 scoop of caramel ice cream).

Here's my code.  Any help is appreciated.

```
    package dessertshop;



import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

abstract class DessertItem 
{
   protected String name;

   public DessertItem() 
   {
      this.name = "";
   }

   public DessertItem( String name ) 
   {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public final String getName() 
   {
      return name;
   }

   public abstract double getCost(int number);
}

class Candy extends DessertItem
{
   private double pricePerPound;

   public Candy( String name, double unitPrice )
   {
      super( name );
      this.pricePerPound = unitPrice;
   }

   @Override
   public double getCost(int amount)
   {
      return( amount * pricePerPound );
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      NumberFormat   formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
      return( "Candy\t" + name + "\t @ " + formatter.format( this.pricePerPound ) + " per pound");
   }
}

class Cookie extends DessertItem
{
    private double pricePerDozen;

    public Cookie(String name, double pricePerDozen)
    {
        super(name);
        this.pricePerDozen=pricePerDozen;
    }

    @Override
    public double getCost(int amount)
    {
        return(amount * pricePerDozen)/12;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return( "Cookie\t" + name + "\t @ " + formatter.format( this.pricePerDozen) + " per dozen");
    }
}

class IceCream extends DessertItem
{
    private double cost;

    public IceCream(String name, double cost)
    {
        super(name);
        this.cost=cost;
    }

    @Override
    public double getCost(int amount)
    {
        return(amount * cost);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        NumberFormat   formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return( "Ice Cream\t" + name + "\t @ " + formatter.format( this.cost ) + " per scoop");
    }
}

public class DessertShop
{
    private String name = "";
    private DessertItem[] menu;
    private int numberOfItems = 0;

    public DessertShop(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        menu = new DessertItem[200];
    }
    public DessertShop()
    {
        menu = new DessertItem[200];
    }

    public void addToMenu(DessertItem item)
    {
        menu[numberOfItems++] = item;
    }

    public void printMenu()
    {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
        {
            System.out.print((i + 1) + ": " + menu[i].toString());
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public double createNewOrder()
    {
        double totalCost = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true)
            {
            this.printMenu();
            System.out.print("What would you like to purchase? (0 to checkout) > ");
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            if (choice == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            System.out.print("How many (lbs. or amount) > ");
            int amount = input.nextInt();
            totalCost += menu[(choice - 1)].getCost(amount);
            }
        input.close();
        return totalCost;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ("Welcome to " + name);
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        DessertShop shop01 = new DessertShop("Chuck D's Dessert Depot");
        Candy candy01 = new Candy("Reece's Pieces", 3.99);
        Candy candy02 = new Candy("Chocolate Covered Raisins", 4.99);
        Cookie cookie01 = new Cookie("Peanut Butter", 5.99);
        Cookie cookie02 = new Cookie("Chocolate Chip", 4.99);
        Cookie cookie03 = new Cookie("Sugar", 4.50);
        IceCream icecream01 = new IceCream("Cookie Dough", 3.00);
        IceCream icecream02 = new IceCream("Vanilla", 2.00);
        IceCream icecream03 = new IceCream("Caramel", 3.50);
        IceCream icecream04 = new IceCream("Rocky Road", 2.99);
        IceCream icecream05 = new IceCream("Mint Chocolate Chip", 3.99);
        shop01.addToMenu(candy01);
        shop01.addToMenu(candy02);
        shop01.addToMenu(cookie01);
        shop01.addToMenu(cookie02);
        shop01.addToMenu(cookie03);
        shop01.addToMenu(icecream01);
        shop01.addToMenu(icecream02);
        shop01.addToMenu(icecream03);
        shop01.addToMenu(icecream04);
        shop01.addToMenu(icecream05);

        double frankOrder = shop01.createNewOrder();

        System.out.println(frankOrder);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you seek, you can format your price at your last line of code:

> System.out.println(frankOrder)

have a look: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

About the other question, reading in from file, I suggest you have a look at csv files: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and how to read them:[here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/)

Comment: Perfect.. got it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hassle too much, you can get decent result with printf:

```
System.out.printf("Price is: €%,d", 12342353563623L);
```

> Output is: Price is: €12,342,353,563,623

[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html%22Formatter%22) on "," flag:

> The result will include locale-specific grouping separators